# MathJax script stuck me everyday!

Tags: discussion

This is actually an old question that I asked [in the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8350536#8350536) but got no satisfied solution.

I can't remember when this began to happen, probably not from the very beginning, but when I noticed, I had been waiting for my computer's reviving everyday for a minute or so when I visited Mathematica.SE for the first time that day.

I admit I've already got used to this, I've developed the habit to drink a cup of water and so on to kill the time, but today I suddenly sobered up: I should ask this formally in meta, to make sure if there is really no way to relieve this, or to draw more attention to this issue if it's currently incurable.

I use Vista 32bit, Chrome 40, on an old 2GHz dual core laptop with 2GB memory. The problem appeared at least from Chrome 25.

[Oleksandr R.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8353959#8353959) mentioned that he suffered the same issue in the chat room. Don't tell me we're the only two!

Comment: You should include as many details of your system and configuration as possible.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Edited. Is it OK?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome comes with awesome [developer-tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) that let you profile and record what is happening on your machine. Have you tried to use them? Open the dev-tools with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and go to *Profiles*. Make sure you have one of the problematic SE pages as favorites in your toolbar so that you can navigate easily to them.

Try "Collect JavaScript CPU Profile" and press *Start*. Navigate to the SE page and wait until it is finished. After this, you can see which script requires a lot of time and you can access which function is the most expensive

[image]

Additionally, note you can turn on rendering information that are directly drawn into the web-site.

[image]

Try to turn on everything except of "continuous page rendering". This might give you additional clues.

Comment: ……I know this may sound ridiculous, but I can't reproduce the stuck behavior anymore since I turned on "Collect JavaScript CPU Profile" for once yesterday, and now even if I restart my computer and visit Mathematica.SE without the dev-tools turned on, the stuck behavior doesn't appear!

Comment: @xzcd This is called *fixing by frightening the bug* :-) If it comes back and you have a way to reproduce it, then you still can try the dev-tools. Just make sure you don't have debugging turned on all the time. I guess the dev-tools are resource hungry.

Comment: Seems that the stuck behavior came back since an update of Vista yesterday. This time it's not frightened. I collect the profile but can't understand it quite well, would you like to have a look?: http://1000eb.com/12ex7

Comment: ……After I uninstalled the troublesome [KB3013455](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_update/kb3013455-ms15-010-causes-font-corruption/8640d38d-19bd-46b6-9af0-6213c05107d3) the stuck behavior disappeared again.

Comment: @xzczd Let's assume you land on a foreign planet, you sit on a computer and try to download something. You don't speak the language, you cannot decrypt the alien signs and the only thing that looks familiar [on the screen](http://i.imgur.com/55xw9BK.png) is a sleeping child, a burning pig and a finger that looks like a hammer hit it. Question: Where would you click? :-)

Comment: Don't worry, here comes a friendly alien who'll point out the right path for you!: http://i.stack.imgur.com/NhKqk.png :D